# Keeping track of "prices" in a SQLite database?

Tags: sql, database-design, sqlite, data-modeling

My Schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
    price TEXT NOT NULL,
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX "item_id" ON "items" ("id");
```

I'm setting price as `TEXT` but it probably should be something different.

The data that I need to keep track of is `$30/day`. So there is a "cost" part of the number (in USD) and a "per something" part. How should I keep track of this data?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite internally stores everything as text, so don't stress out about your type.

I'd change the column name to "price_per_day", and store it that way. If the item you're storing isn't priced "per day", normalize it to a day, then store it that way.